# Angular: error TS2322: Type 'ItemsResponse' is not assignable to type 'string[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting this error with my component not sure what to do?

here is the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-emails',
  templateUrl: './emails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./emails.component.scss']
})

export class EmailsComponent implements OnInit {

test = 'test';
results: string[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    interface ItemsResponse {
      results: string[];
    }

    this.http.get<ItemsResponse>('assets/api/email_list.json').subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data;
      console.log(this.results);
    });
  }

}
```

and then I am getting this error, oddly enough, is working in the browser even with the error?

```
ERROR in src/app/components/emails/emails.component.ts(24,7): error TS2322: Type 'ItemsResponse' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
src/app/components/emails/emails.component.ts(24,7): error TS2322: Type 'ItemsResponse' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'ItemsResponse'.
```

**edit: added json snippet:**

```
[
    {
        "pk": "wGR",
        "created": "2017-10-07T01:42:25.110747Z",
        "email_domain": "domain.com",
        "sender_name": null,
        "sender_email": "user@domain.com",
        "has_user_viewed": false,
        "is_shielded": false
    }
]
```

adding this so we know where we are at with this and for historical reasons so I learn something new here!
**current revision:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-emails',
  templateUrl: './emails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./emails.component.scss']
})

export class EmailsComponent implements OnInit {

results: ItemsResponse[]

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    interface ItemsResponse {
      pk: string;
      created: string;
      email_domain: string;
      sender_name: string;
      sender_email: string;
      has_user_viewed: boolean;
      is_shielded: boolean;
    }

    this.http.get<ItemsResponse>('assets/api/email_list.json').subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data.results;
      console.log(this.results);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Try logging `data` and review the structure. This could be as straightforward as `this.results = data.results;`.

Comment: It looks like  `data` in subscribe parameters is type of `ItemsResponse` and you try to assign it to `results` that you defined as a `string[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit

Now that we have the data structure:

```
[
    {
        "pk": "wGR",
        "created": "2017-10-07T01:42:25.110747Z",
        "email_domain": "domain.com",
        "sender_name": null,
        "sender_email": "user@domain.com",
        "has_user_viewed": false,
        "is_shielded": false
    }
]
```

you should probably create an interface like this:

```
interface ItemsResponse {
  pk: string;
  created: string;
  email_domain: string;
  sender_name: string;
  sender_email: string;
  has_user_viewed: boolean;
  is_shielded: boolean;
}
```

and change the definition of `results` to `results: ItemsResponse[]`.

That means that `this.results` will be an array, each element being an `ItemsResponse` object.

After the request completes, you'll be able to access it as you would expect:

```
this.results[0]["sender_email"]
this.results[12]["pk"]
this.results.map(item => console.log(item.pk))
```

and so on.

Note that in my interface I have used just `string` for the `pk` field, but if you have a limited set of possible values, like `"wGR", "wGA", "wGP"` you can use a string enum type like so:

```
interface ItemsResponse {
  pk: "wGR" | "wGA" | "wGP";
  // ...
}
```

To explicitly explain why you had the error, however, you cannot cast an `ItemsResponse` to a `string[]`, which is what you were doing by asserting the response of your get request as `<ItemsResponse>` (doing this tells the typechecker that `data` will be an `ItemsResponse`), but you then assign it to this.results, which you have declared as a `string[]`. Hopefully the illustration above shows why this won't work.

### Original version

You have a type interface which defines a *field* called `results`:

```
interface ItemsResponse {
  results: string[];
}
```

In your service, you cast `email_list.json` to `<ItemsResponse>`:

```
this.http.get<ItemsResponse>('assets/api/email_list.json').subscribe(data => {
  this.results = data;
  console.log(this.results);
});
```

which means it expects `email_list.json` to look like this:

```
{
  "results": [
    "one@example.com",
    "two@example.com"
  ]
}
```

while it's likely actually

```
[
  "one@example.com",
  "two@example.com"
]
```

So you need to either

1. assign it as `this.results = data.results`, or
2. change the type interface to be simply `string[]`

Comment: changed to this.results = data.results; and now its logging as undefined?

Comment: I was guessing about your data structure. What does `email_list.json` actually look like (can you please update your question with a sample)?

Comment: i appreciate your help, I added a snippet from the json above in my OP

Comment: getting this error now: ERROR in src/app/components/emails/emails.component.ts(12,10): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ItemsResponse'.
src/app/components/emails/emails.component.ts(29,27): error TS2339: Property 'results' does not exist on type 'ItemsResponse'.

Comment: It's because you're trying to access `.results` somewhere, but it doesn't exist. Yeah, remove the `.results` from `data.results` in the get request.

Comment: @SandraWillford Did this comment help ^

Comment: this.results = data; produces: ERROR in src/app/components/emails/emails.component.ts(33,9): error TS2322: Type 'ItemsResponse' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
src/app/components/emails/emails.component.ts(33,9): error TS2322: Type 'ItemsResponse' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'ItemsResponse'.

Answer (score 1):

here: `this.http.get<ItemsResponse>` you are declaring that `http.get`'s response data's type would be of `ItemsResponse`. and before that, inside your class you are declaring that `results` is an array of strings: `results: string[];`. but inside http's response, you are assigning the response to `this.results`.
try `this.results = data.results`.
but make sure that the type of the response is truly of type `ItemsResponse`. maybe use `console.log`