# Typescript class method found as property

Tags: typescript

I have a little bug(?) with my typescript code.
See the following:

```
class Component {
    assertBoolean(): boolean {
       return true;
    }
}

class DummyComponent extends Component() {
}

const components: Component[] = [ DummyComponent ];
```

I got the following typescript error:

> error TS2322: Type 'typeof DummyComopnent' is not assignable to type
>   'Component' Property 'assertBoolean' is missing in type 'typeof
>   DummyComponent'.

I really don't know what I am doing wrong there, basic OOP.

Comment: There is an error in `class DummyComponent extends Component()`. The rest does not matter.

Comment: something similar has being asked here, check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47560868/angular-error-ts2322-type-itemsresponse-is-not-assignable-to-type-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not instantiating the class. `DummyComponent` represents the class itself when used in an expression, not an instance of the class. To instantiate the class you need to use `new` operator:

```
class Component {
    assertBoolean(): boolean {
    return true;
    }
}

class DummyComponent extends Component {
}

const components: Component[] = [ new DummyComponent() ];
```

To keep an array of the classes you need to use `typeof Component`. This represents the type of the class (not an instance of the class)

```
const components: (typeof Component)[] = [DummyComponent];
new components[0]()
```

Comment: Seems legit. I am doing so because the instantiation will be performed by the framework I am using (Angular). I'll just stick with the `any` type. Thanks!

Comment: @ChainList avoid any. Added a version about how to keep classes in the array :)

Comment: I didn't know that, well thank you for that answer! Indeed I want to avoid using `any`.